# How to retrieve the Tiles definition name from within a Preparer?

Tags: java, tiles, web-frameworks, apache-tiles

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the name of a definition in a Preparer, but I can't seem to find an obvious, straight-forward way of doing it.  What I've cobbled together is a sizeable hack, which can only imply that I'm not doing it properly.

Is there a way from within a preparer to get the name of the definition that is being prepared?  I noticed that the only arguments that are passed to the preparer are the org.apache.tiles.request.Request tilesContext and org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext attributeContext.  I presume there must be someway to retrieve it from the tilesContext, but not entirely sure how.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`Definition` implements the `AttributeContext` interface. So I presume you could check whether the `attributeContext` parameter is in fact an instance of `Definition`. If so, you can use the `getName()` method:

```
String definitionName = null;
if (attributeContext instanceof Definition) {
    definitionName = ((Definition) attributeContext).getName();
}
```

If `definitionName` remains null after this code, you're not dealing with a `Definition`, so there's nothing to do anyway.